# Repeated code to check for iOS version

Tags: ios

I use this snippet repeatedly in my app.  So, it is better to read it once and store it in the global variable or appDelegate or just keep executing the snippet whenever needed?

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0"))
    return NO;
return YES;
```

Comment: This isn't an answer in any sense and therefore quite possibly isn't helpful, but: you generally shouldn't need to version check in iOS. Check whether functionality is available using `respondsToSelector:`, `NSClassFromString` and use it if so. Otherwise you're effectively implementing your own little lookup system of feature by version, which is redundant. Of course, that's only helpful advice if availability of functionality is your concern — if it's more like wanting to put a custom skin on a `UIButton` unless it's already got the iOS 7 look then that's different again.

Comment: Yeah, generally you should use respondsToSelecter or one of its kin.  But I have run into occasions where checking the version was necessary, since behavior varied between versions.  If so, your scheme is as good as any, though I'd be tempted to make it a field in AppDelegate.

Comment: @Tommy, agreed with you on respondsToSelector, but in this case, I needed for UI related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say to just keep it in a variable owned by AppDelegate - it's a simple BOOL, so it's not storage intensive.

However, this snippet is not system intensive at all - it's pretty much free performance-wise. Since you are thinking about this kind of optimization, though, it would be better to keep it in AppDelegate.

Answer (score 1):

A contrived example, as in this case is completely unnecessary, but if you want to use this pattern in future to ensure something is only called once, use dispatch_once from GCD:

```
- (BOOL) isIOS7 {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    __block BOOL isIOS7 = NO;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        isIOS7 = SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0");
    });
    return isIOS7;
}
```